# Defining methods with menu in Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, menu, sftp

I have this code just for demonstration in favor for my question.
How can I sort these three commands into three different methods? And also am I thinking right? I already wrote the menu, and I'm starting to grasp Ruby so I would like to learn more.

```
require 'net/sftp'
require 'ostruct'
require 'optparse'

class Sftp
  
  def parse(arguments)
    ARGV << "-h" if ARGV.empty?
    @options = OpenStruct.new
    
    args = OptionParser.new do |args|
      args.banner = "Usage: #{__FILE__} [options]"
      
      args.on("-s", "--set-host=HOST", String,
         "The Host To Connect To") do |set_host|
         @options.set_host = set_host
      end
      
      args.on("-u", "--username=USERNAME", String,
         "Authenticate With A Username") do |username|
         @options.username = username
      end

      args.on("-p", "--password=PASSWORD", String,
         "Authenticate With A Password") do |password|
         @options.password = password
      end

      args.on("-w", "--wharf=WHARF", Integer,
         "Specify The Wharf (Port) The Service Is Running") do |wharf|
         @options.wharf = wharf
      end

      args.on("-m", "--mkdir=CREATE DIRECTORY", String,
         "Create A Directory") do |mkdir|
         @options.mkdir = mkdir
      end

      args.on("-h", "--help", "Show Help And Exit") do
        puts args
        exit
      end

    begin
      args.parse!(arguments)
    
    rescue OptionParser::MissingArgument => error
      puts "[!] ".red + error.message.bold
      exit

    rescue OptionParser::InvalidOption => error
      puts "[!] ".red + error.message.bold
      exit
   end

def connect(arguments)
  Net::SFTP.start(@options.set_host, @options.username, :password => @options.password, :port => @options.wharf) do |sftp|
    mkdir(sftp) if @options.mkdir         
  end

  output("Exiting at => (#{Time.now})")
end
  
def run(arguments)
  parse(arguments)
  connect(arguments)
end

private 

def mkdir(sftp)
  sftp.mkdir!(@options.mkdir)
  output("Creating Directory => #{@options.mkdir}")
end

def output(string)
      puts "----------------------------------------------------------"
      puts " #{string}"
      puts "----------------------------------------------------------"
      end
    end
  end
end

sftp = Sftp.new
sftp.run(ARGV)
```

This is the full code. I hope this is clear enough. Sorry if I wasn't very specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first refactoring step would look like this:

```
require 'net/sftp'
require 'ostruct'
require 'optparse'

class Sftp
  def run(arguments)
    parse(arguments)
    connect(arguments)
  end

  private

  def parse(arguments)
    ARGV << "-h" if ARGV.empty?
    @options = OpenStruct.new
    
    args = OptionParser.new do |args|
      args.banner = "Usage: #{__FILE__} [options]"
      
      args.on("-s", "--set-host=HOST", String, "The Host To Connect To") do |set_host|
        @options.set_host = set_host
      end
      
      args.on("-u", "--username=USERNAME", String, "Authenticate With A Username") do |username|
        @options.username = username
      end

      args.on("-p", "--password=PASSWORD", String, "Authenticate With A Password") do |password|
        @options.password = password
      end

      args.on("-w", "--wharf=WHARF", Integer, "Specify The Wharf (Port) The Service Is Running") do |wharf|
        @options.wharf = wharf
      end

      args.on("-m", "--mkdir=CREATE DIRECTORY", String, "Create A Directory") do |mkdir|
        @options.mkdir = mkdir
      end

      args.on("-h", "--help", "Show Help And Exit") do
        puts args
        exit
      end

      begin
        args.parse!(arguments)
      
      rescue OptionParser::MissingArgument => error
        puts "[!] ".red + error.message.bold
        exit

      rescue OptionParser::InvalidOption => error
        puts "[!] ".red + error.message.bold
        exit
      end
    end
  end

  def connect(arguments)
    Net::SFTP.start(@options.set_host, @options.username, :password => @options.password, :port => @options.wharf) do |sftp|
      mkddir(sftp) if @options.mkdir
      rmdir(sftp) if @options.rmdir
      erase(sftp) if @options.erase         
    end

    output("Exiting at => (#{Time.now})")
  end

  def mkdir(sftp)
    sftp.mkdir!(@options.mkdir)
    output("Creating Directory => #{@options.mkdir}")
  end

  def rmdir(sftp)
    sftp.rmdir!(@options.rmdir)     
    output("Deleting Directory => #{@options.rmdir}")
  end

  def erase(sftp)
    sftp.remove!(@options.erase)
    output("Deleting File => #{@options.erase}")
  end

  def output(string)
    puts "----------------------------------------------------------"
    puts " #{string}"
    puts "----------------------------------------------------------"
  end
end

sftp = Sftp.new
sftp.run(ARGV)
```

Comment: I just tried it, but now I'm getting  `private method 'run' called for #<Sftp:0x00007f5f57102170> (NoMethodError)`

Comment: Just move your `def run` method in the class above the `private` keyword. For example, between the `connect` method and the `private`.

Comment: @spikermann Sorry for busting your chops, but one last question. I did that, but now I'm getting this error `undefined method 'run' for #<Sftp:0x00007fa5d4dab3e0> (NoMethodError)`

Comment: You didn't post your full `Stfp` class in your question, therefore this is a bit hard to answer. But all methods in my answer and the `run` need to be in the `Sftp` class. At least `run` and `initialize` need to be public (defined above the `private` keyword) all other methods might be private (defined below the `private` keyword).

Comment: Ok I posted the full code, because I realized I wasn't specific enough. I hope this is clear now.

Comment: I included all code from your question to my answer. The problem was that you defined some methods nested within the definition of the parse method. Just make sure that the nesting and indentation is correct, that one method has ended properly before defining the next.

Comment: Ah ok, you were very helpful. My teachers will be very happy. :)